# Apache PDFBox 2.0.4 how to validate pdf with subfilter "adbe.x509.rsa_sha1".?

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, pdfbox, pkcs#1

As i can obtain certificate object from cert that is appended in contents part ..i am confused to how to validate/Verify the signed content for PKCS#1 i.e.  adbe.x509.rsa_sha1 . Any help will be appreciated.!!

Comment: An aside question: PKCS#7 / CMS based integrated PDF signature schemes in the last years turned out to be preferred (IMO for good reasons) but recently several questions concerning PKCS#1 based schemes started to pop up. Is there some new context in which the latter ones are preferred?

Comment: That been said, how much do you know about the security stuff? Do you know e.g. your way around with bouncycastle?

Comment: actully for my app i was testing with all types of pdf document where i came across a pdf with this subfilter and so the question. And for bouncycastle not much but yes.

Comment: Ok. Can you share that example document? And what kind of verification are you after? Do you merely want to verify whether the signature matches the signed data? Or do you also want to check the validity of the certificate in question?

Answer (score 0):

```
COSDictionary sigDict = sig.getCOSObject();
COSString contents = (COSString) sigDict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.CONTENTS);
// download the signed content
byte[] buf;
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(infile))
{
    buf = sig.getSignedContent(fis);
}
COSString certString = (COSString) sigDict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.CERT);
byte[] certData = certString.getBytes();
CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
ByteArrayInputStream certStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certData);
Collection<? extends Certificate> certs = factory.generateCertificates(certStream);

// inspired by:
// https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=pades_signing_2.1.5-master/src/main/java/com/opentrust/spi/pdf/PDFEnvelopedSignature.java
ASN1InputStream asn1IS = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes()));
ASN1Primitive asn1prim = asn1IS.readObject();
if (!(asn1prim instanceof ASN1OctetString))
{
    throw new IOException("ASN1 octet string expected, but got " + asn1prim.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
ASN1OctetString oct = (ASN1OctetString) asn1prim;
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certs.iterator().next();
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
signature.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());
signature.update(buf);
System.out.println("Verification result: " + signature.verify(oct.getOctets()));
```

The upper part is taken from the ShowSignature.java example of PDFBox. The lower parts are based on code found in the PDFEnvelopedSignature class in OpenTrust/pades_signing_2.1.5 from Paulo Soares, see license in source code [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=pades_signing_2.1.5-master/src/main/java/com/opentrust/spi/pdf/PDFEnvelopedSignature.java) or [here](https://github.com/OpenTrust/pades_signing_2.1.5/blob/master/src/main/java/com/opentrust/spi/pdf/PDFEnvelopedSignature.java).

A sample file can be found in issue [PDFBOX-2693](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2693).

Update 30.11.2018:

Getting the algorithm with `cert.getSigAlgName()` does not always give the actual algorithm. The link above also shows code to get the correct digest algorithm, insert the following code after the line with "oct = ":

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding", SecurityProvider.getProvider());
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, cert.getPublicKey());
byte[] raw = c.doFinal(oct.getOctets());
DigestInfo di = DigestInfo.getInstance(raw);
String algID = di.getAlgorithmId().getAlgorithm().getId();
```

The valid values are:

```
RIPEMD160  1.3.36.3.2.1            TeleTrusTObjectIdentifiers.ripemd160
SHA1       1.3.14.3.2.26           OIWObjectIdentifiers.idSHA1
SHA256     2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1  NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256
SHA384     2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.2  NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha384
SHA512     2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.3  NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha512
```

However I've never had anything else than SHA1 which is why I have it hardcoded for now.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised about the `"SHA1withRSA"` - in spite of the subfilter name **adbe.x509.rsa_sha1** the hashing algorithm needs not be SHA1.

Comment: You are right… although the PDF specification once mention several in a table and tells "Despite the appearance of sha1 in the name of this SubFilter value, supported encodings shall not be limited to the SHA1 algorithm. The PKCS#1 object contains an identifier that indicates which algorithm shall be used", and at another place it tells "the only value of SubFilter that should be used is adbe.x509.rsa_sha1, which uses the RSA encryption algorithm and SHA-1 digest method".